# How modify a baked animtion?

Tags: animation

I have a FBX model, it contains a skeleton & a animation.
The animation is baked.

I wanna adjust arm_bone's rotation. But I can only make modifications frame by frame.
Is there have any more simple method?

[image]

Comment: You can remove the keyframes between 2 keyframes, change the 2 remaining keyframes the way you want in order to get the movement you want, then in the 3D View > Pose > Animation > Bake Animation. I don't know if you can only bake for one bone or one track only though

Comment: Search for Additive Animation Layers https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iv4GmtYlAHQ

Comment: Or just open NLA Editor, press "Push Down Action" button, rotate the bone at correct position and and keyframe. At strip properties switch "Blending" to "Add".